# PHP upload image name

Tags: php, html, database, upload, web

I want to write a php code that uploads a file name to a database. I want to be able to first just upload the file name. So later i can look up its name and bring up the file. This is what i have so far
HTML code :

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="image_record.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
Please Enter the Member Name.
</p>
<p>
Member or Affiliates Name:
</p>
<input type="text" name="nameMember"/>
<p>
Upload File
<input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
<br/>
</form>
</html>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$name = $_POST["nameMember"];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if (!$con) {
die("can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("snippets",$con);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    //echo $file_name
    $query="INSERT INTO value (file) VALUES ('".$file_name."')";
}
mysql_query($query,$con);
mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

ok so it uploads the file to myphp admin, but not the file name. That is fine, but how do i call the file name from a php code?

Comment: What do you mean by *"how do i call the file name"*? I think what you may mean by this is how to echo it? If so, you need to query it in a loop, using a `while` or `foreach`. I tested your code and it entered the filename into the `file` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using [mysql_ deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) functions

Use ***[PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) / [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)*** functions instead

in `image_record.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];}
    //echo $file_name

    $query="insert into your_table_name (column_name) values('".$file_name."')";
    $res=mysql_query($sql,$query);
}
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$name = $_POST["nameMember"];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if (!$con) {
die("can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("snippets",$con);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $name (
file VarChar(),
Attendance int 
)"; 

mysql_query($sql,$con);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    //echo $file_name

    $query="INSERT INTO value (file) VALUES ('".$file_name."')";
    $res=mysql_query($sql,$query);
}

mysql_close($con);

?>

</body>
</head>

Comment: what is this man? you can paste this by editing your question

Comment: Do you mind showing me what the entire code should look like?

Comment: this is clumsy,you can update your question if you have any doubt?

Answer (score 0):

***Firstly***, I tested your code and it did insert the filename into my DB.

My `file` column was set to `VARCHAR(255)`.

Now, if you want to show the filename after it has been uploaded, use the following: (assuming that's what you're asking).

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM value");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<p>'.$row['file'].' </p>';

}
```

The above code will show all the files in that row after you uploaded.

If you wish to limit it to only one, use `LIMIT 1`

For example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM value LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<p>'.$row['file'].' </p>';

}
```

---

If you want to show the first record only with a limit of one, use:

```
SELECT * FROM value ORDER BY file ASC LIMIT 1
```

If you want to show only the last record with a limit of one, use:

```
SELECT * FROM value ORDER BY file DESC LIMIT 1
```

If you don't want to limit the amount of records shown, then just remove `LIMIT 1`

---

However, if you wish to later retrieve the uploaded file, you won't be able to because you haven't actually uploaded the file.

You will need to use the [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function.